# Html Dynamic form fields value difference

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have the following structure of the form.

**Note:** its dynamic(from jquery) and the same fields are coming multiple times so i have to use `[]` for the field names to get an array.

```
Select users : <input type="radio" name="user_id[]" />
Select Duration :<input type="radio" name="six_months[]" />
OR : <input type="radio" name="one_year[]" />
OR : <input type="radio" name="three_year[]" />
```

The `user_id` is important and can't be left blank, The rest are the options, Means you have to select only one of the duration.

Now **how will i be able to differentiate between the values** that `user X` have `six months` and `user Y` have `one year`.

Is there any better way/approach/Best practice ?

Comment: the index number of every user values will be same. Like if X user is on index 2 than their six_months value will be on index 2 and their one_year value will be on index 2.

Comment: Why aren't the duration options radio buttons or a dropdown?

Comment: @PatrickQ they are radio buttons. But i tried to minimize the question. I am editing it.

Comment: Name the radios the same (so they are a group), each with their own unique `value=""`. Then it would be one name value coming in of `duration[]` with which only one value was chosen. Then you'd just match index to index of those two post vars coming in.

Comment: @IncredibleHat Thanks man, Thats the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use same name for the duration field as `duration[]`, You will be able to get an array and then simply use that array further.

Answer (score 0):

If you can customize your form object so it will be more consistent if you add identifier rather than relying on the indexes. Like:

```
Select users : <input type="radio" name="user_id[skck1][]" />
Select Duration :<input type="radio" name="six_months[skck1][]" />
```

Or if not you then use this php code to match the indexes.

```
$x = array(1,2,3,4);
$y = array('a','b','c','d');

$results = array();
foreach($x as $k=>$v){
  $results[] = array('x'=>$v, 'y'=>$y[$k]);
}

print_r($results);
```

Before that, you also need to validate your form that user must select/check all the fields otherwise your indexes will be out of sync.